# Installation of red5 1.0.5 on windows

Tags: red5, red5-hls-plugin

Can anyone please tell me how to install RED5 media server version 1.0.5 on windows7,i have already tried installing using executable file from https://github.com/Red5/red5-server/releases but jre file isnot there.Also red5 isn't appearing in Administrative tools/services to start the server.

Answer (score 2):

Make it in following steps:

1. Uninstall your previous Java and Red5 install. Reboot.
2. Download JDK 8u45 64 bit and install
3. Install RED5 1.05 windows and install
4. Go to RED5 directory and run install service
5. Reboot
6. Go to services and make sure RED5 service is installed and start service. 7. Set service to start in "Automatic"